# Learning android sprite and got an error with my bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, nullpointerexception

I'm learning how to make sprites on android.

And I got a problem with my bitmap,

```
public class Sprite {
Bitmap b;
BoardGame bg;
int x,y;
int xSpeed,ySpeed;
int height,width;
int direction;

public Sprite(BoardGame BoardGame, Bitmap blob) {
    b = blob;
    bg = BoardGame;
    height = b.getHeight();
    width = b.getWidth();
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    xSpeed = 5;
    ySpeed = 0;
    direction = 0;
}


private void update()
{
    if (x > bg.getWidth() - width - xSpeed)
    {
        xSpeed = 0;
        ySpeed = 5;
        direction = 1;
    }
    if (y > bg.getHeight() - height - xSpeed) {
        xSpeed = -5;
        ySpeed = 0;
        direction = 2;
    }
    if (x + xSpeed < 0)
    {
        x = 0;
        xSpeed = 5;
        ySpeed = 0;
        direction = 3;
    }

    x+=xSpeed;
    y+=ySpeed;
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    update();
    Rect src = new Rect(0,0,width,height);
    Rect dst = new Rect(x,y,x+width,y+height);
    canvas.drawBitmap(b,x,y,null);
}
```

}

(I'm using MyBringBack tutorial), and this is the error I'm getting:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.moshik.tastyfingers, PID: 18872
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.moshik.tastyfingers/com.moshik.tastyfingers.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getHeight()' on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getHeight()' on a null object reference
>                         at com.moshik.tastyfingers.Sprite.(Sprite.java:20)
>                         at com.moshik.tastyfingers.MainActivity$BoardGame.(MainActivity.java:43)
>                         at com.moshik.tastyfingers.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

I gave a resource to 'blob' and for some reason the "getHeight()" doesn't work as I see.

Can someone help me fix that, and explain to me what gone wrong?

edit: my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Bitmap ball, blob;
float x = 0;
float y = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    BoardGame BoardGame = new BoardGame(this);
    ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.aqua_ball_green);
    ball = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ball,170,170,false);
    blob = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.monkey);
    blob = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ball,170,170,false);
    setContentView(BoardGame);
}


public class BoardGame extends View{
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);


    public BoardGame(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    Sprite sprite = new Sprite(BoardGame.this, blob);

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRGB(255,155,155);
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball,x - 80,y - ball.getHeight()/2,null);
        sprite.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();


        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
            invalidate();
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you post your `MainActivity` code, where you create `Sprite` and also the same goes for the `Bitmap`?

Comment: @user8 Done, this is the only activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "and for some reason the "getHeight()" doesn't work"

Your argument `Bitmap blob` that you have passed onto the constructor of `Sprite` is **null**. You try to dereference a null object!

You first *create* `Sprite` and then later `blob`. That's at the point of creation of `BoardGame`, wherein you initialize `Sprite`, `blob` is null.

```
BoardGame BoardGame = new BoardGame(this);//here you create it, but blob is null!
//first here you initialize blob
blob = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.monkey);
blob = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ball,170,170,false);
```

A possible solution would be to just adjust the order of execution in your  `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.aqua_ball_green);
    ball = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ball,170,170,false);
    blob = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.monkey);
    blob = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ball,170,170,false);
    //Put BoardGame here:
    BoardGame BoardGame = new BoardGame(this);
    setContentView(BoardGame);
}
```

That way you would initialize your `BoardGame`, when `blob` is already initialized too.

Hope this clears the issue!